# duende identity server RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync won't pass redirect uri

Tags: identityserver4, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, duende-identity-server, redirect-uri, redirect-uri-mismatch

I'm using Duende Identity Server 6 and trying to get Access Token from my **Identity Server**
in my API Controller using http client base on duende documentation. 
But I get this Invalid redirect uri in my **Identity Server console** logs.
[image]

As you can see the **redirectUri** is null in information log,
and there is my code in **Client API.Controller**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a client credentials flow. The endpoint you need to invoke is `/connect/token`. Is not necessary redirect uri in this flow.